# Number of multigraph configurations

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations

I am wondering on the problem of counting the number  of possible configurations of a multigraph made of $N$ graph-layers.

Each graph-layer has two vertices and one edge. Moreover, each graph-layer shares one vertex with all the others.

The question would be to find all possible configurations of multigraphs made by projecting the layers to one graph.

For instance, for two graph-layers, the two possible configurations are:

1. Two edges and two nodes.
2. Two edges and three nodes.

Configuration 2.  exists in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways. But we only consider one as we assume unlabeled nodes.

In the same fashion, for $N=4$ graph-layers, the number of possible configurations is:
$$\binom{4}{4} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{4}\frac{1}{2!} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\frac{1}{2!}+\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\frac{1}{4!} = 15 $$

For three grah-layers the number of configuraions is 5, and the configurations are drawn below: [image: here].

I am assuming this problem is probably well-known in combinatorics, but it's far from my area of expertise. Has this problem a generalized formula?

It is a very interesting problem and a hint on any literature or textbook  will be highly appreciated.

[**EDIT**] Thanks to Donald Splutterwit for pointing out that the problem is equivalent to finding the number of partitions of a set of size $N$ where we consider neither the order of the partitions nor the order of the elements in each partition.

Comment: What is a "layer" of a multi-graph ? ... can you draw the $5$ objects at the $3$ level and add them into your question ? ... The sequence $1,2,5,15,\cdots$, suggest the Bell numbers (but search OEIS, there will be lots more).

Comment: Calculate the number of configurations for $N=5$ and then see if it is on the list https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C15&language=english&go=Search

Comment: It's indeed 52, thanks for the reference. Can you point me to a software to easily draw the configurations for 3 layers? Else I'll make the drawings using tikz.

Comment: https://www.draw.io/ ... It is difficult & slow to start with ( steep learning curve!) ... personally I would use Paint (in Windows Accessories) it will look like a child drew it, but it will be quick.

Comment: Looking carefully at the calculation you do for $N=4$, I am pretty sure you want the Bell Numbers. They are the row sums of the Stirling numbers of the second kind ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Yes, the problem is equivalent to counting the number of partitions of a set of size $N$ where the order of partitions and elements within partitions are not considered (please see edit).